# How to setup internet connection in a way vpn logs would think I'm logging from different country

Tags: vpn, router, intranet

I have a company laptop which uses a Cisco VPN to log in to the company network in order for me to work.

How do I configure internet I'm using at home in a way where Cisco VPN logs, or another log that can be taken from the company laptop, show a different country that I'm logging into my company network from than the one I'm actually in?

I saw in my router configuration an option to set up a VPN. If I set up a specific VPN on my router and then I connect to this network with my company laptop and connect to the company network via Cisco VPN, will my employer be able to know I'm not logging in from a country I'm connecting to via the VPN configured on the router? Is there a different way how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can "mask" your location by using a double VPN connection. In other words, connecting to a personal VPN with your desired location and then connecting to your company VPN. I am not 100% sure about this but maybe you can give it a try.

> It is possible for a double VPN service provider, such as NordVPN, to
> support multiple VPNs from a single device, with appropriate
> configuring of the NordVPN Double VPN feature.

Source: [https://www.techtarget.com/searchnetworking/answer/Can-you-have-two-VPN-connections-to-the-same-machine-simultaneously#:~:text=It%20is%20possible%20for%20a,greater%20security%20for%20the%20connection](https://www.techtarget.com/searchnetworking/answer/Can-you-have-two-VPN-connections-to-the-same-machine-simultaneously#:%7E:text=It%20is%20possible%20for%20a,greater%20security%20for%20the%20connection).

Comment: That's not the correct use case for the OP. The OP wants to chain the VPN connections.

Comment: You need two separate VPN providers for chaining and that's what the asker wants..

Comment: I can't use any other VPN on my company laptop, I want to do it on my local network I'm connecting to with company laptop.

Comment: I guess you could configure a VPN tunnel via your router on your local network and then connect to the company one.

Comment: @StevanMilic Thanks, I thought about that. The thing is won't the company know I'm connecting to another VPN ? Not sure about all of the things you can find out from the cisco vpn logs.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you don't have local admin on your company's laptop or if you do have, it is not a good idea to make such adjustments on corporate devices.

I'd propose the following solution:

remote host -> VPN tunnel to host located in the preferred country -> use company's VPN as usual.

The local VPN agent should think it is in the preferred country.

Use a site-to-site tunnel and configure the network device to forward all traffic to the desired gateway (look for static routing). As I don't know the details, I'd advise also to disable split tunneling.

Also try to find log structure in Cisco product documentation, but as far I know, by default in logs, there is a remote IP that will be equal to the public IP of your host located in the preferred country.